# How to create procedure and call/Execute in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How to create procedure and call/Execute  in PostgreSQL

Comment: There is a free manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-programming.html

Answer (score 0):

To return a result "table", use a function not a procedure:

```
create function Proc_StudentLogin(Sid bigint)
  returns setof students
as
$Body$
  select * from students where id = sid;
$Body$
language sql
stable;
```

```
-- Use function:
select * 
from Proc_StudentLogin(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
--Create Procedure

Create procedure Proc_StudentLogin(

Sid bigint,

inout get_result refcursor)

Language 'plpgsql'

AS $Body$

Begin

open get_result for 

Select * from Students where id = sid;

End

$Body$;



--Call procedure

Call Proc_StudentLogin(1,'result');

fetch all in "result";
```

Comment: If you want to return a result use a function, not a procedure